# To hide certain attributes from the proxy generation in c#

Tags: c#

I need certain properties to only be accessible within the assembly. I do not want them to be exposed in the proxy so that they can accessed by the clients.

```
public class B: A
{
  public string Name { get; set; }

  public string Age { get; set; }
}

public class A
{
   public string Salary { get; set; }
}
```

In the above example, the `A` class's property, `Salary`, should only be accessible in the assembly. Have tried using the `[ScriptIgnore]` attribute. However, the property was still accessible in the client. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Have you tried using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/internal or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/protected-internal?

Comment: Yes. But still the properties were accessible to the client.

Comment: Which engine/package/framework is used for exposing the class to the client side?

Comment: @bijum how were they accessible to the client when using the `internal` access modifier, typically it shouldn't be possible unless you declare in your assembly `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("client")]`.